# asking to questions from remote machine while running commands over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, ssh

I have some servers and I want to install SSL on all of them
I wrote the following script(I should run it from each servers):

```
#!/bin/bash
 #something to install SSL on centos
 #....
 #
```

note: I should run script like this(because of assigning ssl certs):

```
./ssl-conf <<EOF
   > <CountryNmane>
   > <StateName>
   > <LocalityName>
   > <OrganizationName>
   > <OrganizationUnitName>
   > <CommonName> 
   > <EmailAddress>
   > <ChallengePassword>
   > <CompanyName> 
   >EOF
```

now my question:
I want to write a bash to do it with numbers of my servers.I wrote something like this(I should run it on my machine):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read pass port user ip; do
    sshpass  -p$pass -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p $port $user@$ip <<EOF <<SSH
       US
       something
       newyork
       test
       test1
       test2
       test3
       challengepassword
       test4
    EOF #End of asking questions

    #commands to install SSL
    #commands to install SSL
    #commands to install SSL
    SSH #end of commands running on remote machine
done <<___HERE
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.1
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.2
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.3
___HERE
```

Is this syntax right?

does not work.

any idea?

thank you in advance

Comment: This is somewhat beside the point, but you really should be using key-based authentication instead of allowing root access with a password.

Comment: no problem..I checked by using password variable and worked...the problem is how to ask questions from remote host

Comment: You can't have to "here-document" redirections on the same line...that is, runing `somecommand <<EOF <<SSH` isn't go to do anything useful (it will probably just ignore the `<<EOF`).

Comment: thank you///do you have any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SSH and *heredoc*

You could'nt make **two** *here-doc* on same command line!

But you could write distant `ssh` command entirely on command line:

```
Script=$'while read foo ;do\n    echo $HOSTNAME $foo\ndone'
echo "$Script"
```

Note the use of *double-quotes*!

```
while read pass port user ip; do
  sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p $port $user@$ip "$Script" <<eoparams
    US
    something
    newyork
    test
    test1
    test2
    test3
    challengepassword
    test4
eoparams
done <<eodests
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.1
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.2
    mypasswd  22  root  192.168.1.3
eodests
```