# Sending long commands with Expect and ssh

Tags: ssh, expect

I have an *Expect* script in my *Tcl 8.5* framework.
It is being used to spawn a `ssh` from *Ubuntu 11.10* to other *Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)* PC.

I manage to login successfully via *Expect*.
Also, short commands that I issue are being recognized successfully by my script, e.g. `ifconfig`.

But when issuing with `exp_send` long commands,
they are being read by the `expect` command with " \r" (*space* and `CR`) injected between every X characters.

For example, the parameter to `exp_send` is (Validated using `exp_internal 1`):

```
sudo tshark -c 1 -i ethernet0 -f 'broadcast and ether host 00:00:00:00:00:00' -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.time_epoch -e wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.supported_rates -e wlan_mgt.extented_supported_rates\r
```

After sending this, the `expect` command reads it as:

```
sudo tshark -c 1 -i ethernet0 -f 'broadcast and ether host 
 00:00:00:00:00:00' -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.tim 
e_epoch -e wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.supported_rates -e wlan_mgt.extented_supported_ra 
tes
```

(notice the extra single whitespace at the end of the first 3 lines)
How can I send a command without having " \r" injected within?

---

**Edit #1 (29 January 2014, 08:30 UTC):**
This problem occurs also with another commands, like `echo`.
For example, I've sent with `exp_send` the string:

```
Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3!Hello World4!Hello World5!Hello World6!Hello World7!Hello World8!Hello World9!Hello World10!Hello World11!Hello World12!Hello World13!Hello World14!Hello World15!Hello World16!Hello World17!Hello World18!Hello World19!'\r
```

And `expect` reads it with ' \r' injected between, e.g.:

```
echo 'Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3! \rHello World4!Hello World5!Hello W
```

You can see the following live example, received using `exp_internal 1`:

```
expect: does "\u001b]0;root@MyFedora15:~\u0007[root@MyFedora15 ~]# " (spawn_id exp9) match full buffer full_buffer? no
".+"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\u001b]0;root@MyFedora15:~\u0007[root@MyFedora15 ~]# "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp9"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\u001b]0;root@MyFedora15:~\u0007[root@MyFedora15 ~]# "
send: sending "echo 'Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3!Hello World4!Hello World5!Hello World6!Hello World7!Hello World8!Hello World9!Hello World10!Hello World11!Hello World12!Hello World13!Hello World14!Hello World15!Hello World16!Hello World17!Hello World18!Hello World19!'\r" to { exp9 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.+' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp9) match full buffer full_buffer? no
".+"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=no
expect: does "echo 'Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3! \rHello World4!Hello World5!Hello W" (spawn_id exp9) match full buffer full_buffer? no
".+"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "echo 'Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3! \rHello World4!Hello World5!Hello W"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp9"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "echo 'Hello World0!Hello World1!Hello World2!Hello World3! \rHello World4!Hello World5!Hello W"
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.+' is ''. Not usable, disabling the performance booster.
```

[This is **basically** my Tcl8.5 code](http://pastebin.com/jng57ieU) (modified for readability).

Comment: Are you sure that's how it's sent, or is it just how it's displayed? Turn on debegging (`exp_internal 1`) to answer that question.

Comment: @glennjackman: Indeed I'm positive, already verified it with `exp_internal 1`...

Comment: Does it happen with other long commands? Can you do a test maybe with `echo`?

Comment: @glennjackman: Indeed it happens also with `echo`, see my edit.

Comment: Don't do that: It's generaly a very **bad idea** to use `expect` and `ssh` (together)! Use *key based access* and remote scripts instead. look [this answer to anoter related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21364205/1765658)

Comment: @F.Hauri: Still don't understand why it's a bad idea. The security aspect doesn't bother me too much here.

Comment: This implie generaly having password or sensible information **hardcoded** in **clear text**... And is generally simplier and more readable by using *remote scripts*. They could be *here docs* so you could build your all script from *start point* too...

Comment: Even if security aspect is not a matter in **there**, It not a *good practice* to learn and work on... day to days.

Comment: This does not appear to be a problem with `send`: that's how the remote shell is **displaying** the command. Does the command (tshark or echo) actually execute successfully? I bet it does.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, the commands execute successfully. But this is actually my problem - reading the command with the string ' \r' injected within. I need to read it without ' \r'.

Comment: After you send a command, expecting `.+` doesn't seem very helpful. You should expect to see your prompt, then you can parse `$expect_out(buffer)` to get the sent command and all the output.

Comment: @glennjackman: But I do test for the prompt after the `expect` command, see the notes that I've written after it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
send "tshark -c 1 -i ethernet0\\\r"
send " -f 'broadcast and ether\\\r"
send " host 00:00:00:00:00:00'\\\r"
send " -T fields -E header=y -\\\r"
send "E separator=, -E quote=d\\\r"
send " -e frame.time_epoch -e \\\r"
send "wlan.sa -e wlan_mgt.supp\\\r"
send "orted_rates -e wlan_mgt.\\\r"
send "extented_supported_rates\r"
```

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for a way w/o intentionally injecting `\r`. Thx!